# Convexity of function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

How is possible check that function $e^{x^TAx}$, where $A$ is positive definite matrix, is convex?
I try this way: Let $\theta \in [0, 1]$, $q = 1 - \theta$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $$f(\theta x + qy) \leq e^{\theta^2r^2 + 2\theta qrs + q^2s^2} \leq e^{\theta r^2 + qs^2},$$ where $s^2 = x^TAx$, $r^2 = y^T Ay$.

The first inequality is fulfilled due to Cauchy – Schwarz inequality.

But I dont know that doing next, I can't come up with inequality such that done this:

$e^{\theta r^2 + qs^2} \leq \theta e^{r^2} + qe^{s^2}= \theta f(x) + q f(y)$

Comment: the last line is just the convexity of $e^x$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're allowed to use that but you can use the property of convexity of composition of functions. hog(x) is convex when h is convex and non decreasing and g is convex, which is the case for this problem. this property easily comes from second order derivative of the composition function assuming the functions are twice differentiable and both function domain in R, but this property works exactly same when domain of the function g is also a vector(I don't know how to prove this tho). you can find more on this on page 83 and 84 of the book convex optimization by boyd.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Generally stream of consciousness answers works better in literature, not so much for mathematics.